# Elegant way to set element's css width to fit 'most' of the content? by a regex pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width

I have a `<select>` element, and `<option>` elements.

Rather than hardcoding the `width` to `90px`, im looking for a way to set the width to fit a **regex'd portion** of the `<option>` contents

The preferred regex would be `LOREMIPSUM#\d{0,5}`

In other words,

- is there a way for the `max-width` and `min-width` of the `<select>` to fit nicely around just the LOREUMIPSUM# part?
- **I dont want** the width of `<select>` to fit all the  content,  just the first part by that regex pattern.

```
    <select 
        id="someId" 
        name="someName" 
        class="someClass" 
        size="1" 
        onchange="someMethod();" 
        style="width:90px;">
            <option value="a0D3u00000BhNCxEAN">LOREMIPSUM#0263 abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc</option>
            <option value="a0D3u00000Bh7qFEAR">LOREMIPSUM#0262 user tests</option>
            <option value="a0D3u00000BgovaEAB">LOREMIPSUM#0258 dogs</option>
            <option value="a0D3u00000BgovVEAR">LOREMIPSUM#0257 cats</option>
            <option value="a0D3u00000BgovVEAR">LOREMIPSUM#10000 some text</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think something like the below might work. Untested.

```
var myOpts = document.getElementById('someId').options;


function biggestNumberInArray(arr) {
  const max = Math.max(...arr);
  return max;
}

var subTextLengths=[];
Array.from(document.querySelector("#someId").options).forEach(function(option_element) {
    let option_text = option_element.text;
    //let option_value = option_element.value;
    let regex = new RegExp('LOREMIPSUM#\d{0,5}');
    let subText = regex.exec(option_text);
    let subTextLength = subText.length;
    subTextLengths.push(subTextLength);
    
});

document.getElementById('someId').style.width = biggestNumberInArray(subTextLengths);
```